# Jquery else не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно, чтобы код в блоке `else` срабатывал, но не могу понять, как должно выглядеть условие для этого.

Почему else не срабатывает? При клике на второй чекбокс открываются блоки которые соответствуют его атрибуту, но когда выбираешь первый, блоки не пропадают.

```js
$('input[data-group]').on('change', function(){
        var group = $(this).attr('data-group');
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $('[data-item-group="'+group+'"').show();
        } 
        else {
            $('[data-item-group="'+group+'"').hide();
        }
    });
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" checked name="radio">
<input type="radio" name="radio" data-group="items1">

<div data-item-group="items1" class="d-none">blocks 1</div>
<div data-item-group="items1" class="d-none">blocks 1</div>
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладкой

Comment: Отладка не при чем, мне нужен конкретно совет по решению.

Comment: Почему не при чём? Хочешь узнать почему на первом не работает? Включи отладку и посмотри какие там данные и проанализируй

Comment: У первого чекбокса нет data-group, а событие change привязано к селектору `$('input[data-group]')`

Comment: Node_pro, я понимаю, а как исправить?

Comment: скрывай все элементы до проверки `is(:checked)`

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае `else` никогда не выполнится, так как для `radio` обработчик `onchange` вызывается в случае выбора этого элемента, а значит внутри обработчика `$(this).is(':checked')` всегда будет возвращать `true`.

В качестве решения достаточно скрывать все элементы и затем показывать только нужные.